# Incorrect work of scengraph xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, user-interface

I need help.
In any good editors I have simple mechanism to work with UI. But XCode it's not good editor. My question is in the following:

I created UIView and set any constraints like here http://take.ms/g27uy

[image: MainStoryboard]

But if I run this to iphone6s simulator, then all children's shift right like here http://take.ms/JH2er

[image: iPhone and 6S]

WHY? All controls(button + text) lie on this view. Why is this happening?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make something that looks like a toolbar or tab bar but isn't one. Don't. If you want a toolbar or tab bar, use a toolbar or tab bar. It doesn't have subviews and its bar items don't have constraints; they are automatically positioned.

Comment: or you can go with default one for tabbar man @Busalaev

Comment: yes, i want to make control like toolbar. and don`t understand why it`s not working.

Comment: probably just due to Constraints given by you

Comment: If i put UITableView here and set same contraints then local components to cell transform automaticly. But here same view..what is the differents?!

Comment: currently for custom tabbar you are use UIView?

Comment: Yes. Ordinary UIView.

Comment: You set constraint for that UIView, which is like a container. What about the constraint of the objects, in that container? can you please share that, too? I think there is something wrong on that part.

Comment: I dont`t set cinstraint there. http://take.ms/YvXog they length like subview of super view. In the case of UITableViewCell it`s worked correct.. but here not.

Comment: you just want custom tabbar ?

Comment: Yes, with flexible working with buttons. Somehow I used the standard solution. But there were problems with the maximum size of the buttons

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/igA4JPSqqN3D4z6N2d5LdvqMaYFt4R, is it viewed as iphone 7, iphone 6, or other, And in with which simulator are u running the code. please check this image, https://www.dropbox.com/s/flm60tfiq7uit88/dummy.png?dl=0

Comment: If you do not put constraint on those controls/objects they will not look same in different sized device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below solution will help you

**Step 1**

Create view like TabBar and give it proper Constraints. as image describe below with L,T,B & H Constraints.

[image]

**Step 2**

Add One subview to that view and give it all Constraints to superview with equal width and height. Now suppose you are having 3 tabs then the added subview height should be 1/3. so you just need to give height Constraints's multiplier to 1/3 as below image

[image]

and your Main view (Custom Tabbar view) should look like this

[image]

**Step 3**

Add Second view for second tab item with same width and height Constraints as first tab item. image for it as below

[image]

Make sure the first and second tab items no need of trailing Constraints the last item contains it.

Comment: L,T,B & H - what constraints? )

Comment: L - leading, T - trailing, B- bottom , H- height

Comment: Thank you! I will try it! And will write later about the result.